# Information about Uber API Maps endpoint

Tags: uber-api

The "/v1/requests/{request_id}/map" endpoint returns the following link in Sandbox environment.

[Map in Sandbox](https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/map)

How does this work in production -

- Is it just a static image showing a route from pickup to destination (similar to the one we see in Uber rider history screen)?
- Or is it a dynamic URL showing the current location of the vehicle with additional details?
- Is the returned map href accessible after the trip is completed?
- Is there an API that returns a static map as displayed in the "Uber Rider History" in Iphone app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Is it just a static image showing a route from pickup to destination (similar to the one we see in Uber rider history screen)?
> - Or is it a dynamic URL showing the current location of the vehicle with additional details?

It's the latter. It includes details about the trip's progress and updates in real time. It's the same kind of link that you generate when sharing your own trip status using the "share ETA" button in the mobile app.

> - Is the returned map href accessible after the trip is completed?

Yes but only for a couple of days. After that it yields a 404.

> - Is there an API that returns a static map as displayed in the "Uber Rider History" in Iphone app?

No.